# Ruby: Collect index from Array/String Matchdata

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, string, match

I'm new to Ruby, here's my problem : I would like to iterate through either an Array or String to obtain the index of characters that match a Regex.

Sample Array/String

```
 a = %q(A B A A C C B D A D)
 b = %w(A B A A C C B D A D)
```

What I need is something for variable a or b like ;

```
#index of A returns;
[0, 2, 3,8]

#index of B returns
[1,6]

#index of C returns
[5,6]
#etc
```

I've tried to be a little sly with

```
z = %w()

a =~ /\w/.each_with_index do |x, y|

 puts z < y

end
```

but that didn't workout so well.
Any solutions ?

Comment: When you say that it "didn't work out so well", can you please describe how so?

Comment: I get a each_with_index method undefined for MacthData object error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get each character's index as a hash, this would work:

```
b = %w(A B A A C C B D A D)

h = {}
b.each_with_index { |e, i|
  h[e] ||= []
  h[e] << i
}
h
#=> {"A"=>[0, 2, 3, 8], "B"=>[1, 6], "C"=>[4, 5], "D"=>[7, 9]}
```

Or as a "one-liner":

```
b.each_with_object({}).with_index { |(e, h), i| (h[e] ||= []) << i }
#=> {"A"=>[0, 2, 3, 8], "B"=>[1, 6], "C"=>[4, 5], "D"=>[7, 9]}
```

Answer (score 3):

For array, you could use

```
b.each_index.select { |i| b[i] == 'A' }
```

For string, you could split it to an array first (`a.split(/\s/)`).

Comment: Is there a way of iterating through the Array instead of naming each character by hand?

Comment: @user3437917 What do you mean by `naming each character by hand`?

Comment: e.g for this answer, the A in the block was named. I would like to do the same of the B character without having to write a new block of code for B - or maybe I just didn't understand the code - I should try it first- newbie:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count occurrences of each letter you can define helper method:

```
def occurrences(collection)
  collection = collection.split(/\s/) if collection.is_a? String

  collection.uniq.inject({}) do |result, letter|
    result[letter] = collection.each_index.select { |index| collection[index] == letter }
    result
  end
end

# And use it like this. This will return you a hash something like this: 
# {"A"=>[0, 2, 3, 8], "B"=>[1, 6], "C"=>[4, 5], "D"=>[7, 9]}
occurrences(a)
occurrences(b)
```

This should work either for String or Array.